# Should be std::set<T>::value_type a const?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I see that **map** have a const key on `value_type` but **set** not work the same way.

If `std::map<T>::value_type` are `std::pair<const Key, T>` would `std::set<T>::value_type` be `const Key`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: No, it's just `Key`. But all the iterators of `std::set` are const_iterators, so it's still impossible to modify elements (in general ways).

Comment: @songyuanyao: But what if some new methods with not const iterators are added in future? As open-close priciple say: "Open for expansion - close for modification".

Comment: @88877: I know how it works. My question is a **should be** ... ?

Comment: @IsaacPascual Non-const iterators would break the whole concept of `std::set`, which is usually implemented as some form of a binary tree. If you had non-const iterators, you would be able to change keys and each such change might result in modification of the whole tree.

Comment: @IsaacPascual That won't happen. Same as the key of `map`, it's not supposed to be modified; the order of elements is sorted in `set`, modification on elements might break the whole `set`.

Comment: If some future method expose std::set<T>::value_type on some way (direct or indirect) (not only via iterator) is more secure to implement it as const Key like map... Is better on expansion point of view. Or somebody can explain disadvantages of doing that const?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is not possible. Although it may seem reasonable to make `value_type` const, keep in mind that `value_type` is also used in the signature of methods like `insert`, for example:

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type&& value);
```

This function takes advantage of move semantics in C++. If `value_type` were const, it would no longer work. As you mentioned in the question, a similar issue has already occurred with `std::map`. That's why initially `std::map` had the following `insert` method:

```
template <class P>
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(P&& value);
```

Instead of:

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type&& value);
```

This is because for `std::map`, `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`, where `Key` is const, and it cannot be moved in any case. Note that the latter was added in C++17. You can find the related discussion in [LWG 2354](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2354), although it is still an awkward function.